# Check for duplicate when editing a record in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates

I'm having problems with a piece of code and wonder if someone can help.

I have a form that submits information to a MySQL database, I have the correct code for checking to see if the submitted product code already exists, and if so shows a warning message and the record is not added.

That code is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listing_1 WHERE product_code='$product_code'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows) {
   adminwarnmessage("DUPLICATE REFERENCE CODE","FAILURE - <b>$product_name</b> has <b>NOT</b> been added because the reference number already exists.");
}
```

That works fine for Data Entry, however I have another form that allows users to edit the record, this is what is causing me a problem, as the above code only tells me that there is already a matching record in the database, Of course when I try to save (update) the record it now tells me I can't because it is a duplicate.

What I would like to happen is that it doesn't allow users to choose another productcode that already exists, but I want them to be able to update the record using the same product code the form fetched from the database.

Hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To improve your query performance add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your select query and select only the `product_code` instead of all data, as you just want to check duplicates so no need to get all the details.

Comment: Thank you for that information, I never thought about that part

Comment: @doniyor just mansion a common way that when you want to check if something exist in DB just put a limit and select only one or two fields as necessary. A best practice for the programming life with SQL.

Comment: @doniyor when you write something like `SELECT * FROM listing_1 WHERE product_code='$product_code'"` to check something exist in DB just put a `LIMIT` and select one or a few fields as results. Just telling a best practice to follow.

Comment: @doniyor I just put a comment for the original question code. If you clearly look at the question code, do you see any field selected from the select query is used? No right. Retrieved values are not used. So the effect is same regardless of the number of rows retrieved or the fields retrieved. I feel like you wrongly has got an idea that I have posted something here in comment as an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23012/discussion-between-shantha-kumara-and-doniyor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
I have resolved this issue by making $productcode field a unique Index.
Now when editing if there is a duplicate..

Mysql does not accept the update query, it returns an error code

I trap that error code and include it in an if statement...

if( mysql_errno() == '1062' )

adminwarnmessage("DUPLICATE REFERENCE CODE","FAILURE - **$product_name** has **NOT** been added because the reference number already exists");

}
adminmessage("Item Updated", Congratulations you updated $productname succesfully");

}

This now allows editing of $productcode but does not allow it to be changed to one already used in the database.

Thank you to everyone who took the time to offer help

Answer (score 1):

If you have id (primary key) then You will have to compare with id of that product before updating the record. For example

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listing_1 WHERE product_code='$product_code' AND id!=$id"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if ($num_rows) { 
    echo "duplicate record";
}
```

Here $id is the id of the product that you should have while editing the record.

Comment: from the question, I think `product_code` is used as a key (i.e. it is unique).

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, I think if I'm correct that would tell me that there is a duplicate record and therefore not allow the edited form to be updated in the database? I need to allow them to save (update a record) with same $productcode

Comment: No, it will simply allow user to update the record with same product code. You can first try this and check.

Answer (score 1):

following is the step you need to follow when you managing the Database

1. First you need an primary key(auto_increment) in "ID" field
2. When you execute insert query that time first check where record is already available or not. if not available than only you should execute insert query.
3. use primary key filed for update, delete etc...

if you follow the above step than you never face this problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, ID field is already a primary key, the $productcode field isn't. The code works great for entering a record initially, it's when I come to edit the record, the user needs to be able to change the $productcode field if they want to, but **not** to one that is already in the database. Or they may edit other fields and click update and it saves the record with the same productcode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps checking for duplicate occurrences in both of `insert` and `update` statement? If so, you shouldn't. Duplicate entry is relevant only when "inserting". You shouldn't use the same check for `update`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. The user needs to be able to change the product code as well as any other field when they edit the record. Hence it needs to check for duplicates again when updating.

Answer (score 0):

why the same code for update also? you can use another query for updating which is better for debugging if you have problems later. try this

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE listing_1 SET product_code='$new_product_code' WHERE product_code='$product_code' AND id='$id'");
if($result) {
   echo "your product was updated.";
} else {
   echo "your product is not in DB";
}
```

EDIT: be careful in updating or inserting things, take always `id` to check unless your `product_code` is unique

Comment: Thank you for answering, would that also check to see if the new productcode they entered is already in the database?

Comment: @Drew, if the new productcode is already in db, it will be set again and nothing happens which is okay for you. because you never update someoneelse's productcode because you are also comparing with id.